# How we can manipulate the momentum of a particle?

Tags: momentum, subatomic

Is there any way to affect a particle's momentum value?

Comment: The answer I have given below may seem trivial, but if you are somehow thinking that momentum is an intrinsic property of the object than you have gotten hold of a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You apply a (net) force (i.e. push it).

Recall that the generalized version of Newton's 1st law is that force is proportional to the rate of change in momentum:

$$ \vec{F} = \frac{\mathrm{d} \vec{p}}{\mathrm{d}t} \,,$$

or in the language of impulse ($J$)

$$ \vec{J} =  \Delta\vec{p} = \langle \vec{F} \rangle \Delta t \,,$$

with $\langle \rangle$ meaning the time-average of the enclosed quantity.

Written this way the law is completely valid in special relativity as well as in Newtonian mechanics, which is nice because much of particle physics occurs are relativistic relative velocities.

Comment: That's not trivial, i thought the same but there were a lot of descriptions witch confused me about the fact that one can maniplulate the momentum of a single particle or not.Thank you.